# Why does my App crash? Drawer

Tags: java, android

i have the Problem that my App doesn't even start,it just crashes.
I would be very thankful for help. :)
I already tried to use `listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);`

But then there are no Elements in the drawer.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.CE.DE;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView listView;
private String[] planets;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    planets=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets);

     listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>                         
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,planets));
    }
 }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <FrameLayout

    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left">
    </ListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Please share the stacktrace

Comment: Ahem... listview isn't initialized.
That should have been clear from the message in your LogCat...

Comment: @chokdee "Null Error"

Comment: Initialize your list view

Comment: Pleaser verify if you have really entries in your Arraylist (debugger, logcat etc)

Comment: Where you added `listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);`? Because we can't see it. And post your stacktrace in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is that you have not initialized your `ListView`

### Solution

create a new `ListView` object -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    ....

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    listView.setAdapter(...);

    }
 }
```

Comment: Why he have to create a new instance? this is wrong

Comment: Actually it works,but there aren't now items in the drawer. @chokdee

Comment: I corrected it. You have to get the listView reference from the XML and cast it to a ListView object

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code**

```
 package com.CE.DE;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView listView;
private String[] planets;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    planets=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>                         
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,planets));
    }
 }
```